# NoClassDefFoundError for inner class when renaming class with ASM

Tags: java-bytecode-asm

I'm trying to rename a class using ASM before writing it out to a JAR file which then gets loaded back in later. I've implemented my ASM remapper as follows:

```java
private static class MyClassRemapper extends Remapper {
    private final String className;

    public MyClassRemapper(Class cls) {
        className = cls.getCanonicalName().replace(".", "/");
    }

    @Override public String map(String internalName) {
        if (internalName.startsWith(className))
            return internalName.replace(className, "New" + className);
        return super.map(internalName);
    }
}
```

It all works fine if I feed it some `OuterClass`. However, if I then add an inner class `InnerClass` to `OuterClass`, then after I reload the JAR when I try to call a method (via reflection if that matters) on an instance of `NewOuterClass` I get the error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/.../NewOuterClass$InnerClass
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3139)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethodsRecursive(Class.java:3280)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3266)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2063)
    at ...
```

From the error it's clear that ASM is succeeding in renaming some of the references to `InnerClass` but obviously not the class definition itself. I've looked at implementing `mapInnerClassName` but I'm pretty sure that I don't need to do that, as that's altering `InnerClass` itself. 
Anyone have any ideas?

**Edit**: If I change the `map` function to;

```java
    @Override public String map(String internalName) {
        if (internalName == className)
            return internalName.replace(className, "New" + className);
        return super.map(internalName);
    }
```

so that only the top-level class is renamed, then I run into a different error when I attempt to run the inner class constructor:

```
NoSuchMethodError: com.(...).OuterClass$InnerClass.<init>(Lcom/.../NewOuterClass)V
```

which suggests that the methods of the inner class is failing to be renamed properly.

Comment: Do you know how inner classes are compiled?

Comment: So the inner class is lifted to top level and the name of the outer class is prepended to it's name? I've added a little more information to what happens if I don't also rename the prepended outer name.

Comment: You have at least two class files, one for the inner class and one for the top level class. You must transform *both* classes. In fact, you must adapt any class which may have a reference to one of the two classes, but these two classes also need to be stored under the new name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) in his comment provided the solution. The problem was that I was only remapping the class file of the outer class. However the inner class also has its own class file. The solution is to apply `MyClassRemapper` to that and write that out as well.